# Are there undocumented ast.literal_eval limitations?

Tags: python, literals

Using, python 3.4, that works:

```
>>> ast.literal_eval("2 - 1")
1
```

but that doesn't:

```
>>> ast.literal_eval("1 | 2")
raise ValueError('malformed node or string: ' + repr(node))
ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.BinOp object at 0x0000000003338978>

>>> ast.literal_eval("1 ^ 2")
raise ValueError('malformed node or string: ' + repr(node))
ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.BinOp object at 0x0000000003338400>
```

All values are literals, there's no difficulty performing logical operations when it can perform additions, substractions...

Why can't I perform logical operations using `ast.literal_eval` ?

Comment: I thought it was related to constant folding, but that does not seem to be a case, as `1|2` seems to be correctly folded to `3` (according to `dis` module).

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski Additionally, >>> ast.dump(ast.parse("1 ^ 2"))
'Module(body=[Expr(value=BinOp(left=Num(n=1), op=BitXor(), right=Num(n=2)))])'

Comment: @pradyunsg: `ast` does not do any constant folding, so I'm not sure what point you are trying to make

Comment: @Eric That the constant folding does not happen at the ast level. At least not until the result from `ast.parse`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it's [not implemented that way](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/ast.py#l75) in Python 2.7.

At a glance, addition is only supported in order to enable `complex` literals like `1 + 2j`, since it rejects `2j + 1`.

In python 3.5, [the implementation](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/ast.py#l40) was [made a bit more lenient](https://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/884c71cd8dc6/), and does not restrict addition in this way.

Comment: Hah. You beat me to it.

Comment: No. Python 3.5 still restricts it.

Comment: @pradyunsg: Try `ast.literal_eval('2j + 1')`. Works in 3.5, but not 2.7. So 3.5 is less restrictive

Comment: Ah. I thought you were comparing 3.4 and 3.5.

Comment: You're right, support for Add and Sub was added to support complex literals, see [issue4907](http://bugs.python.org/issue4907).

Answer (score 1):

It's just not implemented that way. The only operators "white-listed" are `Add` and `Sub`. [3.4](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/ast.py#l74), [3.5](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/ast.py#l74)

<strike>This could be filed as a bug-report to http://bugs.python.org, asking for support of more operators.</strike>